# Reserve app name for next year

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My customer needs an app for this year but the name he choose dis already in use. I advice him to change completely the name for this year but he wants to be sure to have the desire name next year.

So what if I upload the next year app with the desired name now and than, when it will be approved, I deselect all territories in iTunes Connect (my app will be removed from all App Store territories worldwide). The App will remain "inactive" until next year, and the name can't be use from others, right?

How to be sure that the name does not already exist when I create the app? If I create a new app and digit "Facebook" as a name it returns no error.. I think it iTunes connect needs the SKU to check the availability..

Answer (score 0):

How do know that the name will be available next year?

Concerning reserving the name:

- As soon as you create a new app in iTunesConnect and have a valid developer account (which you have, otherwise you couldn't create the app) the app's name is reserved for you. You don't have to do any further request or something, the creation is enough.

Comment: What do you mean with "How do know that the name will be available next year?"

Comment: Well if the app name is taken right now, how do you know it will be available next year?

Comment: I've wrong explained. It is precisely because I take it this year that next year won't be available for others.

Comment: But if someone has an app named like that, I don't get why the name should be available next year...